# Laravel custom request validation

Tags: laravel, validation, request

i have been trying  in create check on form validation on laravel
i need to query input with date and check more than check with many messages 
like

```
if(){
   $this->errorSchema->addError($error, $name); //symfony 1 way
}
```

how and where should i do that i have been thinking in creating custom validtaion but it returns true or false i need the date in the query to display like "this place is used for user XXX" XXX is data i got in the query 
 i want to return multi  error if some record exist like

```
$resultset  = 'select person form events where date < "some date"';
if ($resultset[enddate] > 'somedate'){
my error message should be "you cant add this event as $resultset['person'] overlape in this date "
}elseif($resultset[startdate] > 'somedate'){
i need here to return deffrent error message like "start date is overlapping with resultset['person']"
}
```

i am using requests class in laravel so please recommend me a method to override or any other way to this in laravel 
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be please be more elaborate on what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to SELECT data which you'd like to return, your "XXX", from table by user's input.
Simple SELECT *** FROM table WHERE smth = user's_input;
If it return smth, you can just add it to your validator such as:
 "this place is used for user".$smth;
Else (if nothing returned, you send to user your default answer.)

Also if you add more code it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: thanks alot this is what i want to do i dont know where to add this if and else in laravel :)